# How to unmarshall S3 XML in Go?

Tags: go

I am making an http `GET` request on the root directory of my s3 bucket to list the contents. I would like my application to parse the contents to understand what's in the bucket.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>my-bucket</Name>
    <Contents>
        <Key>one.json</Key>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>three.json</Key>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>two.json</Key>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

To parse it I am trying to use this:

```
    type S3Content struct {
        Key     string   `xml:"Key"`
    }

    type S3ListBucketResult struct {
        Contents []S3Content `xml:"Contents"`
    }

    type HttpS3Response struct {
        ListBucketResult S3ListBucketResult `xml:"ListBucketResult"`
    }

    resp, _ := http.Get("https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.example.com")
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var parsed HttpS3Response
    xml.Unmarshal(body, &parsed)

    fmt.Println(parsed.ListBucketResult.Contents)
```

However the `Contents` slice appears empty. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the root key isn't included in the path

```
type S3Content struct {
    Key     string   `xml:"Key"`
}

type HttpS3Response struct {
    Contents []S3Content `xml:"Contents"`
}

resp, _ := http.Get("https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.example.com")
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

var parsed HttpS3Response
xml.Unmarshal(body, &parsed)

fmt.Println(parsed.Contents)
```